# Node.js - Insert into adds 0 instead of string

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, node-telegram-bot-api

I am trying to insert some data with node.js. I installed MySQL support via npm, but It still seems to fail to input the right strings with INSERT INTO.
(the row types in the database are tinytext and the strings are smaller then 255 charachters.)

Here is my code
https://hastebin.com/komikahatu.http

The expected output is that it inserts the arguments (what is catched by /name) and the username from the user that executes the command (/name).

```
console.log('Dirname: ' + __dirname);

const bot = require('../core.js');
bot.on("polling_error", (msg) => console.log(msg));

var config = require('../config.json');

var mysql = require('mysql');
var sqlhost = config.sql.host;
var sqluser = config.sql.user;
var sqlpass = config.sql.password;
var sqldb = config.sql.database;

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: sqlhost,
    user: sqluser,
    password: sqlpass,
    database: sqldb
});

bot.onText(/\/name (.+)/, (msg, match) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;
    // 'msg' is the received Message from Telegram
    // 'match' is the result of executing the regexp above on the text content
    // of the message

    let username;
    const name = match[1].toString(); // the captured name

    if(msg.from.username !== ''){
        username = msg.from.username;
    }

    var setnickname = {
      username_: username,
      nickname_: name
    };

    var sql = con.query('INSERT INTO nickname_data VALUES (?)', setnickname, function (err, result){
        console.log(sql.sql);
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return;
        }
        console.error(result);
    });

    if (name !== "undefined") {
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Welcome ' + name + '!');
        // bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Welcome ' + msg.from.name + '!');
        // config.information.normalusername = name;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, add your code to the question.

Comment: @jarlh - Done! ^^

Comment: According to [the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries), `values` is an array and you cannot just put a single `?` and expect it to spread the data to the table columns.

Comment: @dube - I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql - How can I use variables to input a string in the database?

Comment: @R_Flintstone are you sure? your import says you use the mysql package, not sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var setnickname = {
  username_: String(username),
  nickname_: String(name)
};

var sql = con.query('INSERT INTO nickname_data SET ?', setnickname, function (err, result){
    console.log(sql.sql);
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return;
    }
    console.error(result);
});
```

You can also pass the second parameter as an array when using `VALUES` keyword in the query.something like

```
var setnickname = [String(username),String(name)];

var sql = con.query('INSERT INTO nickname_data(username_,nickname_) VALUES (?,?)', setnickname, function (err, result){
    console.log(sql.sql);
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return;
    }
    console.error(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `SET` keyword instead. Replace your query with this.

```
INSERT INTO nickname_data SET ?
```

node's `mysql` module considers object as arrays so it will not use the keys you provide. It will index it as `0,1...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to stringify your object  : `JSON.stringify(setnickname)`

```
  var setnickname = {
      username_: username,
      nickname_: name
    };



 var sql = con.query('INSERT INTO nickname_data VALUES (?)', JSON.stringify(setnickname), function (err, result){
        console.log(sql.sql);
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return;
        }
        console.error(result);
    });
```